# Sort RDD in Spark before publishing it to Kafka?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

In my code, I first subscribe to a Kafka stream, process each RDD to create an instance of my class `People` and then, I want to publish the result set (`Dataset[People]`) to a specific topic to Kafka. It is important to note that not every incoming message received from Kafka maps to an instance of `People`. Moreover, instances of people should be sent to Kafka in exactly the same order as received from Kafka.

However, I am not sure if sorting is really necessary or if the instances of `People` maintain the same order when the respective code is run on the executors (and I can directly publish my Dataset to Kafka). As far as I understand, sorting is necessary, because the code inside `foreachRDD` can be executed on different nodes in the cluster. Is this correct?

Here's my code:

```
val myStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[K, V](streamingContext, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[K, V](topics, consumerConfig))

def process(record: (RDD[ConsumerRecord[String, String]], Time)): Unit = record match {
case (rdd, time) if !rdd.isEmpty =>
    // More Code...
    // In the end, I have: Dataset[People]
case _ =>
}

myStream.foreachRDD((x, y) => process((x, y))) // Do I have to replace this call with map, sort the RDD and then publish it to Kafka?
```

Answer (score 0):

> Moreover, instances of people should be sent to Kafka in exactly the same order as received from Kafka.

Unless you have a single partition (and then you wouldn't use Spark, would you?) the order in which data is received is not deterministic, and similarly order in which data is send won't be.  Sorting doesn't make any difference here.

If you need a very specific order of processing (it is typically a design mistake, if you work with data intensive applications) you need a sequential application, or system with much more granular control than Spark.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Maybe I missed the point and I should not be using Spark at all. I simply want to subscribe to a topic from Kafka, process the data and then publish it back to Kafka on a different topic. Consumers of these topic will process the messages as they are streamed from Kafka and the order matters in my case.