# Design flaw in Spark Streaming App by using only one partition?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am developing a streaming app with Apache Spark. The app receives sensor data by subscribing to a Kafka topic named `sensor`. The purpose of the app is to filter the sensor data, transform it and publish it back to a different Kafka topic named `people` for other consumers. The messages in topic `people` must have the same order as they arrived in topic `sensor`. Thus, I am currently using only one partition in Kafka.

Here's my code:

```
val myStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[K, V](streamingContext, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[K, V](topics, consumerConfig))

def process(record: (RDD[ConsumerRecord[String, String]], Time)): Unit = record match {
case (rdd, time) if !rdd.isEmpty =>
    // More Code...
    // Filter RDD, transform to JSON, build Seq[People]...
    // In the end, I have: Dataset[People]
    // Publish to Kafka topic 'people'
case _ =>
}

myStream.foreachRDD((x, y) => process((x, y)))
```

Today, I asked a question on how to achieve the correct ordering in Spark, after transforming it into my `People` data structure.

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49881081/8516723) indicated that using Spark with a single partition is not wise and that this actually might be a design flaw:

> Unless you have a single partition (and then you wouldn't use Spark, would you?) the order...

I am now wondering whether I can improve the overall design of my application (change the map-reduce flow) or if Spark is not a good fit for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

While this is primarily opinion based **you are using tools**  which are designed for:

- fault tolerant,
- distributed,
- parallel,
- processing, without specific order guarantees

**to solve problem defined** as:

- sequential,
- non-distributed,
- with strict order guarantees,
- possibly breaking fault tolerance (due to large amount of data placed on a single executor).

where:

- single threaded consumer from fault tolerant queue

**would be perfectly sufficient**.

So subjectively speaking there is a serious design flaw here.

Answer (score 0):

In your case Kafka is not the right choice. Kafka only maintains the total order over the messages within a partition. The parallelism or scalability of Kafka is purely depended on the no: of partitions on a particular topic. The flaw is completely with the design.

> If you really want to preserve the order you can have a epoch
>   timestamp in your data and once you transform the data you can sort
>   the data and store it.